# Reference for Galois Theory of infinite field extensions.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I would like to ask what is in your opinion the best place to learn about Infinite Galois Theory that requires not much knowledge of topology. I am searching for a text that explains the notions needed or properly references them, as I am not very familiar with topology. I tried Lang's Algebra (which I particularly like as a text) but it does not contain this subject. I had the same luck with other Galois theory texts that I checked, including Escofier and Edwards. I have a background in Category theory if this helps.

Comment: Try Karpilovsky's Topics in Field Theory. To get a feel for infinite Galois groups that is more than mere formalism, you should know a particular type of topology, namely the topology on the p-adic integers ${\mathbf Z}_p$ and its unit group ${\mathbf Z}_p^\times$. The Galois group of ${\mathbf Q}(\mu_{p^\infty})/{\mathbf Q}$ is isomorphic to ${\mathbf Z}_p^\times$ as a topological group, where $\mu_{p^\infty}$ is the group of all $p$th power roots of unity.